# who uses "replace audio clip" in protools 10?

Tags: pro-tools

i need a hand with this. i'm cutting a tv series at the moment and all i want is to replace all the edited clips of a certain recording in my session with an eq'd version of the same clip. specifically a sound in my ambiance tracks.

i want the sames parts of the original clip to be replaced with the same parts of the replacement clip. this is essential.

no matter what combination i choose from the "replace clip dialog options" box, it will not do this for me. it only effects the highlighted clip and never replaces all the clips in the session, and never chooses the same edit points as my original clip.

can i have a chat with someone here, preferably on the phone, to work this out. my ambs editor is delivering his tracks and i'd like to have him switch out sounds without having to individually fix all the sounds i need replaced.

and if you can't help me and know someone that could, please let me know as well.
cheers,
P.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can help you with this...  You can try relinking the current files to the new files... Pull out the original track in its entirety with no edits to a new track, and rename with the exact same name as the file you're trying to replace it with (the file cannot be already in the session or it will not let you rename it. If it's already in the session remove it from the session but do not delete),then "save as" your session with a new name (so that you can go back to your previous version if things go wrong) and close it. Now remove the original file from the Audio Files folder (move it somewhere safe in case your need back later) and keep the new file in the Audio Files folder, now when you reopen the session it should link the renamed clip to the new file, and all the other versions that are on your session.

Comment: thanks gus. i appreciate the reply. yes, that is the option to do what i need. what i'm wondering is why that "replace clip" function is not working if it's purpose is indeed what i need it to do. protools touts it as a tool for post production, if this is the result then they are helping our community very poorly.

if anyone has success in post with this function i'd really like to hear from you.
cheers,
P.

Comment: Yeah, it sucks, it really seems like the "replace clip" should do what you're saying, but unfortunately it only works if the clips have the same start time or end time, and it will always replace a clip by putting the new clip from start at the replaced clip start boundary.